# LibGDX touch differences between emulator & phone

Tags: java, android, libgdx

While trying to develop a small game with LibGDX, I have a behavior that I don't explain : when I run my game in Android Studio Emulator (Nexus 5X API28) and on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S20), I have noticed a difference that I can't explain :

- on the emulator, the touch (emulated with a click) is detected as expected
- on my phone the touch is detected ~50-100 pixel higher than expected

My guess is that there is something to do with the way LibGDX handle the phone resolution and/or ratio

Here is a sample of the type of code I have:

```
LevelScreen(final PixGame game) {

    this.game = game;

    mTouchPoint = new Vector3();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 720, 1280);
    FitViewport viewport = new FitViewport(720, 1280, camera);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, 720, 1280);
    viewport.update(game.ScreenWidth, game.ScreenHeight, true);
    mStage = new Stage(viewport);


    InputProcessor processor1 = new InputAdapter() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
            game.mTouchUp = false;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
            game.mTouchUp = true;
            return false;
        }
    };
    InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(processor1,mStage);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);

    Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
   if(game.mTouchUp) {
        mTouchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        camera.unproject(mTouchPoint);
        game.mTouchUp = false;
        Gdx.app.debug("TOUCH", "Touchpoint coordinates : " + mTouchPoint);
   }
}
```

I have removed all the game part on the code above, this is just the way I detect and handle touch event (and probably it's not the smartest way but hey, I'm not a pro-developer).

I have a PNG image as a background, and if I touch the same spot on the emulator and on my phone, I have the following result :

- EMULATOR :    Touchpoint coordinates : (90.0,1103.7681,0.0)
- PHONE :       Touchpoint coordinates : (95.33334,1054.3251,0.0)

The X coordinate is about the same (within the margin of error of my finger), the Y coordinate has always a minus 50-100px gap. I have tested many times on different positions on the screen and still the same behavior.

Any guess what I should do to handle this? Maybe the difference of screen ratio between the two (16:9 vs 16:10) ? Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After different tries, I've figured out what was happening : the problem was indeed coming from the ratio that is different between the two phones (16:9 vs 16:10).

In order to neutralize that, I have changed the line

```
FitViewport viewport = new FitViewport(720, 1280, camera);
```

with

```
Viewport viewport = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.stretch, 720, 1280, camera);
```

This is now handling the touch coordinates the same way on the 2 devices.